# JBOSS: where to find jboss.xml

Tags: configuration, jboss

Sorry if my question seems to be silly, but I cannot find something relate on Google.

I need to config something for JBoss server (For example, set JNDI name for EJB...). In tutorials that I have read (On the internet or books), they config those information in `jboss.xml`.

But, I cannot find this file in JBoss folder. (maybe somewhere here but I haven't found yet. So, please give me a link).

After that, I have thought that put `jboss.xml` into Web-INF folder of project. But, it seems strange to me, because when I create EJB Project, I don't see Web-INF folder (It just appear when I choose type of project is Web (Dynamic|Static) Project). If my conclusion is true, please tell me where to put `jboss.xml` in EJB Project, for example.

Thanks :)

Comment: Which version of JBoss AS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the link for how to configure EJB's with all types.
[EJB3-JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/)